# PHP socket client in loop itertion

Tags: php, sockets, loops

I want to implement a client socket in PHP.

The socket type is TCP / IP and runs a full-duplex channel.
The client must send requests to the server every second, so it must be run in a loop.

Do I have to recreate and connect to the socket for each request? 
Or is it better to create and connect to the socket outside by the loop and then manage the communication?

```
<?php
   while (true) {
      //management of the pid here
      //create the socket
      $socket = socket_create (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
      //send the request
      $sent = socket_write ($socket, <query>, <length>);
      //get the answer
      $response = socket_read ($socket, 1024);
      //close the socket
      socket_shutdown ($socket, 2);
      usleep (500);/ / wait remote host
      socket_close ($socket);
      sleep (1);
   }
?>
```

I have already implemented the socket connection outside the loop and the management of requests inside.

But the connection remains active for a few minutes then returns an error on the endpoint connection.

Is it necessary to use socket_bind in this situation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should connect the socket once outside the loop, then use it for the entire application session. Disconnect the socket when the loop finishes.

Comment: the problem is that the loop must always remain active. I have to use specific options for persistent connections (after a while returns error on the endpoint). What is the best way to handle reconnections?
thanks

Comment: If you get an error, exit the loop, reconnect, and go back into the loop.

Comment: Whereas I'm implementing a client:
the socket must be created with the option socket_bind?
thank you very much

Comment: `socket_bind()` is usually only used in servers. Clients use `socket_connect()`.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a socket is consuming a lot of resource and since you are not connecting to multiple points you should create the socket outside the loop.